# How to find bearing of a given object and solve the following question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

A plane is flying 510 mph on a bearing of 295°. A wind of 35 mph is blowing at a bearing of 130°. Calculate the ground speed of the plane and its bearing.

I have the following picture that shows my work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcP7Z.jpg

I don't understand bearing properly, can anyone explain it a bit clearly to me on how I can go about and solve this problem? I don't see a problem with the diagram, an explanation along with the correction to the diagram would really help

Comment: I'm guessing you have some knowledge about vectors (specifically velocity vectors). Bearing is just the direction of a velocity vector on the earth, a map of the earth, or similar. A bearing of 0 degrees is due north (assuming you're bearing is relative to true north). 90 degrees is east, 295 degrees is approximately west northwest, 130 degrees is close to southeast, etc. To solve the problem you'll need to add the two vectors. BTW, the image loaded very slowly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you define "bearing" of an aircraft's path differently than I do. I define it so that the zero bearing points toward the top of the page and 90 degrees points to the right, because that's how it is on aeronautical charts. But that isn't the reason you got the wrong answer; if you *consistently* measure bearing so that zero bearing is toward the right and 90 degrees is toward the top of the page, then (assuming no other errors) you would get the correct numeric results.

I found at least three errors in your calculations. First, you used $130$ rather than $35$ as the length of the wind vector. 
You also mishandled the angle you got from the arc tangent function;
I'm not quite sure how you got the final result you got, but it looks like
you *subtracted* the result of the arc tangent from $270$ degrees, 
and when you rounded it to an integer you chose $251$ when the nearest integer to $270 - 19.9$ is actually $250.$
The correct answer (if the wind speed really had been $130$)
would have been $289.9$ degrees.

On top of all that, the calculations are so weirdly disorganized that even the grader apparently couldn't figure out what you were doing. The "sign error" they marked ($-215.53$ to $215.53$) was actually *not* one of the several errors. (At least, what you wrote was equal to the value it was derived from on the line above it.)

Part of the disorganization is having equations for one of the early steps of the problem at the bottom of the workspace, with later steps of the calculation above them, and with stray "$=$" signs to the left of some things where there's no equal thing to the left or above them.
You also seem to want to put every vector inside an absolute value, that is,
you write $\lvert \vec v\rvert + \lvert \vec u\rvert$ where you intended to take the sum of two vectors, that is, $\vec v + \vec u.$

But what really makes your paper hard to understand, I think, is that you decided to subtract $90$ degrees from all the bearings in the question.
So instead of taking $510\cos(295^\circ)$ and $510\sin(295^\circ)$
as the coordinates of your air velocity vector, you take
$510\cos(205^\circ)$ and $510\sin(205^\circ).$
If you can deal with trig functions of $205^\circ,$ you can deal with
trig functions of $295^\circ,$ and you don't have the extra $90^\circ$
that you have to remember to add back at the end.

Converting a vector from magnitude and direction into rectangular components does not have to be this complicated.
If the vector $v$ has magnitude $\lVert v\rVert$ and direction $\psi,$
the component of $v$ in the "zero bearing" direction is
$\lVert v\rVert \cos\psi$ and the component in the
"$90$ degrees bearing" direction is $\lVert v\rVert \sin\psi.$
The angle $\psi$ is just the direction angle exactly as it was given to you,
in this case the bearing.

Also remember when you convert from components back to magnitude and direction, the arc tangent function only has output from $-90$ degrees to $90$ degrees. That's $180$ degrees of coverage. The other $180$ degrees' worth of directions that vectors can go will never be just given to you by the arc tangent function; instead, it will give you the opposite direction, and you have to add or subtract $180$ degrees to make it right.
One way to see the correct answer is to plot the components of the vector;
a quicker way is, if the "$\cos\theta$" component of the vector is negative, add or subtract $180$ degrees from the arc tangent.
The way to remember that is that the cosines of the angles you can get from the arc tangent function are all positive, so if the angle *should* have a negative cosine, the arc tangent gives you the wrong direction.

Comment: Wait so we can just do <510 cos 295, 510sin295>. But i thought when given bearings we had to convert it? I put 130 as my angle and not the magnitude for my wind thing It probably was cause of the picture quality thing. So for the diagram to have been correct i should've put 90 on the bottom axis and tried to solve it?

Comment: I write software related to aircraft flight planning, in which I have often had to to deal with the bearings of aircraft, wind, and ground paths. My practice is that if $\lVert v\rVert$ is the speed and $\psi$ is the bearing, the _northward_ component is $\lVert v\rVert \cos\psi$ and the _eastward_ component is $\lVert v\rVert \sin\psi.$ I don't convert angles. If you _must_ convert angles (and the only reason to, in my opinion, is if your teacher would take off points if you didn't), the conversion is (math angle) = 90 - bearing. To convert back, bearing = 90 - (math angle).

Comment: so everytime they give me an bearing angle I just subtract 90 from the bearing?

Comment: No, if you must convert, you subtract the bearing from $90.$ For example, a bearing of $40$ is an angle of $50$ degrees according to the usual way angles are plotted on an x,y plane. A bearing of $140$ becomes an angle of $-50.$ That's $90 - 140,$ not $140 - 90$; notice the $-$ sign. Ask your teacher if you really need to do this when the question and answer are both going to be bearings, such as in the question here. I wouldn't advise arguing about it (no point really), just be aware that "in real life" people generally define their angles one way and don't convert back and forth.